# Scroll in X inside column on overflow

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

When the content of the second column overflows then all the page content is scrolled.

How can the first column be fixed in the same place when scrolling the second column on overflow-x?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3 bg-primary">
  </div>
  <div class="col-9">
    <table class="table">
      <tr>
        <td>d1</td>
        <td>d1</td>
        <td>d1</td>
        <td>d1</td>
        <td>d1</td>
        <td>d1</td>
        <td>d1</td>
        <td>d1</td>
        <td>d1</td>
        <td>d1</td>
        <td>d1</td>
        <td>d1</td>
        <td>d1</td>
        <td>d1</td>
        <td>d1</td>
        <td>d1</td>
        <td>d2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just hide the `overflow` across the page and just make the second column scrollable by using CSS like the example below:

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<style type="text/css">
    body{
        overflow:hidden !important;

    }
</style>
</head>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3 bg-primary" style="overflow:hidden">
      </div>
      <div class="col-9" style="overflow:auto !important;">
        <table class="table">
          <tr>
            <td>d1</td>
            <td>d1</td>
            <td>d1</td>
            <td>d1</td>
            <td>d1</td>
            <td>d1</td>
            <td>d1</td>
            <td>d1</td>
            <td>d1</td>
            <td>d1</td>
            <td>d1</td>
            <td>d1</td>
            <td>d1</td>
            <td>d1</td>
            <td>d1</td>
            <td>d1</td>
            <td>d2</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
```